# How to get available (free + purgeable) disk space on MacOS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to get available disk space on MacOS. The trouble is, that "About This Mac / Storage" reports the available space, which consists of two parts:

- free space - this is typical free space on the disk, also reported by e.g. `df -h`
- purgeable space - some files are marked as purgeable and can be removed by OS if disk space runs low

I've tried several packages that use `df` or Posix calls to get this information, but they all report only free space. How to get the same value I see in About This Mac to prevent confusing my users?

Comment: Did you try out node-diskusage? please go and check https://github.com/jduncanator/node-diskusage

Comment: Tried it right now, same issue. Does not include purgeable space.